# How to find set of words in column of sentences and paste the founded word in the same row in the available cell

Tags: excel

I have a column A with sentences in it.

```
Column a    Column b Column c  

Sentences   Word 1  Word 2  1
Sentence 1
Sentence 2
```

In that particular column A i need to find set of keywords like

```
Column J  Column K

Word 1.1    Word 2.1 
Word 1.2    Word 2.2
Word 1.3    Word 2.3    
Word 1.4    Word 2.4
```

...

If any of the above keywords exists in the Column A then it should be paste over the next available cell in the same row.

```
Column a   Column b    Column c

Sentences   Word 1     Word 2   
Sentence 1  Word 1.1
Sentence 2  Word 2.4
```

```js
Dim col As Range, cell As Object
Dim col1 As Range, cell1 As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Keyword").Select
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set col = Selection

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set col1 = Selection


    For Each cell In col
    Range("B1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Line1:
    Selection.Find(What:="bone", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = cell
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
    GoTo Line1
```

I was trying the above codes and my excel hanged up if run this code.

I'm a beginner in macro, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kyle cell.offset(0,500).end(xlleft) = "bone"

Statement is not working. And i have succeeded with the below code.

```html
 For i = 1 To 50
               If cell.Offset(0, i).Value = "" Then
               cell.Offset(0, i).Value = tag
                Exit For
                         
                End If
             Next i
```

Any other short method there?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim col As Range, cell As Range
Dim col1 As Range, cell1 As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set col = Sheets("Keyword").Range("a1:" & Sheets("Keyword").Range("a1").end(xldown).addresslocal)

For Each cell In col
   If instr(1,cell,"bone") <> 0 then
      cell.offset(0,500).end(xltoleft) = "bone"
   end if
Next cell
```

This code will loop through all contiguous cells in column A and if it finds "bone" it will make the next available cell in the row equal "bone".

Your code did not seem to be aligned with what you said you were trying to accomplish. This should get you started.

Comment: cell.offset(0,500).end(xlleft) = "bone"